# integration of NetSuite with either WePay or with Stripe

Tags: integration, stripe-payments, netsuite, stripe.net

I am doing some research for a NFP in the USA and we want to find out if anyone (a company or an individual) has either:
a) done an integration of NetSuite with either WePay or with Stripe.
b) released a product that helps other places integrate the two. If you know of anyone can you please let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

http://www.celigo.com/ is a Netsuite integration firm that has done work with services very similar (aka payment platforms). In Answer to A/B they haven't done an integration of Netsuite with WE Pay or made a product that would integrate the two. That being said, it's a good place to start and I would recommend contacting them since it sounds like you're after an integrated service/product.

Answer (score 0):

[SuiteSync](http://SuiteSync.io/) is a robust integration between Stripe and NetSuite. It supports a number of different configurations and has been battle tested with some of Stripe's larger users for over a year.

Full disclosure: I built SuiteSync with a team at Stripe.